# How to install MVVMLight through nuget

Tags: nuget, mvvm-light, nuget-package

I need to add MVVM Light toolkit to an existing project.
I run nuget command.. My project is in 4.5 Framework. I got this error

```
Attempting to resolve dependency 'MvvmLightLibs (≥ 5.0.2.0)'.
Install-Package : 'MvvmLightLibs' already has a dependency defined for 'CommonServiceLocator'.
At line:1 char:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  MvvmLight
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPa 
ckageCommand
```

I installed through extensions and updates and it got installed but when i tried to create a new  mvvm project using visual studion wizard same this dependency error arises.

How to resolve this..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Install the latest version of NuGet

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal I'm sorry, but I have to disagree with your comment. Not only do I personally think that it was indeed a valid answer, it actually solved the problem for the OP. So I don't understand why you're questioning its validity as an answer. Plus, nowhere was Sievajet "critiquing" or "requesting clarification from the author", so I don't see the relevance of that comment either.

Answer (score 0):

i agrees with Sievajet.  solved the same problem by upgrading to the latest version of NuGet